# crypto-js DES (or Triple DES) Encryption in CBC Mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, extjs, dojo

I need to communicate Encrypted data between my Erlang/OTP Web Server and JavaScript. I have checked out **[Crypto-js.js Library](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/)**. I would like to encrypt my data using **[DES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard)** in **[CBC Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Cbc_encryption.png)**.
 Problem is, on the library site, there is no example showing how to do this. Anyone has an Example, please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it !

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/files/2.5.3-crypto-sha1-hmac-pbkdf2-blockmodes-DES.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// CBC with default padding scheme (iso7816)
var crypted = Crypto.DES.encrypt("Message", "Secret Passphrase", { mode: new Crypto.mode.CBC });
var plain = Crypto.DES.decrypt(crypted, "Secret Passphrase", { mode: new Crypto.mode.CBC });

// CBC with ansix923 padding scheme
var crypted = Crypto.DES.encrypt("Message", "Secret Passphrase", { mode: new Crypto.mode.CBC(Crypto.pad.ansix923) });
var plain = Crypto.DES.decrypt(crypted, "Secret Passphrase", { mode: new Crypto.mode.CBC(Crypto.pad.ansix923) });

</script>
```